# Why my code mod rewrite .htaccess not work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why my code mod rewrite `.htaccess` not work ?

i test to load page `www.example.com/products_type/ipod/black`

when i load page, it's not echo `products name` and `products color`.

How can i do that ?

THIS MY CODE products_type.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
echo $_GET[products_name];
echo $_GET[products_color];
?>
```

THIS IS MY CODE .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ /products.php?products_name=$1&products_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^products_type/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ /products_type.php?products_name=$1&products_color=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Try quoting them `$_GET['products_name'];` and `$_GET['products_color'];` otherwise, they may be treated as constants.

Comment: Fred -ii ---- it's work , could you please advice why `$_GET[products_name];` not work but `$_GET['products_name'];` work

Comment: Because, without the quotes, it's being treated as a constant. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php - I posted an answer below to close the question.

Comment: Fred -ii---- but when i not use mod rewrite `$_GET[products_name];` is work

Comment: `mod_rewrite` to tell you the truth, is not my strong point. I couldn't say why it's working without it, sorry. I won't lie to you ;)

Comment: and if i want to use `www.example.com/products_type/ipod/red` and `www.example.com/products_type/ipod` and `www.example.com/products_type/red` , How to apply .thaccess file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$_GET['products_name'];
$_GET['products_color'];
```

by not quoting them, they are being treated as [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Answer (score 1):

Your rules are out of order. Keep your rules like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^products/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ products.php?products_name=$1&products_id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products_type/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ products_type.php?products_name=$1&products_color=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```